# Replace items in a list with unique items starting from 0

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
Y=[1018, 1018, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1019, 1019, 1017]
```

What's the most pythonic way to replace each number with

- the lowest unused integer (>=0), if the number has not been seen before
- the same integer that has been used to replace the number otherwise

So that the list becomes:

```
Y=[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

It's not important that first element is 0, but there must be a unique maximal matching (= assignment) between the two lists of numbers, i.e. also this is a good solution:

```
Y=[3, 3, 4, 0, 2, 5, 6, 6, 1]
```

EDIT: what I tried is a for loop using find, my solution is very ugly, I know there is better way to do it, it's not relevant how bad I did it :D

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service if you want to get a proper answer you need to add your code that you have tried so far!

Comment: Do you additionally want to have `1018` appear as the same integer if it appears later in the list? `[1018, 1011, 1018]` should be `[0, 1, 0]` or `[0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, [0,1,0] is correct (it's like a substitution of terms)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because So is not a code writing service!

Comment: for what it's worth, I agree with OP that sample code is ***not*** necessary to answer this problem. SO is not a code-writing service, but this is a snippet at best, and the question does a sufficiently good job of explaining what should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is to convert the values to a `set()` and `enumerate()` them, store the pairs in a dict, and use a mapping list comprehension to create the new list:

```
>>> Y=[1018, 1018, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1019, 1019, 1017]
>>> mapping={v:k for k,v in enumerate(set(Y))}
>>> Y1=[mapping[y] for y in Y]
>>> Y1
[5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 4]
```

Comment: thanks this is much shorter and elegant than anything I could ever think of!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a `defaultdict` with `itertools.count`, eg:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

dd = defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c))

Y=[1018, 1018, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1019, 1019, 1017]
mapped = [dd[el] for el in Y]
# [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

How this works is that a `defaultdict` will return the value for an existing key but where that key doesn't exist, it will assign the key to a default value - in this case that value is the next number in sequence.

Comment: Ooh that's interesting! I like it.

Comment: I don't understand this one. Why would it return 0 also the second time?

Comment: I think the logic would be clearer if you declared c as just a local variable, as opposed to (ab)using the python default variable scope. Very cool nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I typically use. The core logic is basically the same as what @JonClements wrote.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# mypy static typing annotations
from typing import Dict, Generic, List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Interner(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = [] # type: List[T]
        self._keys = {} # type: Dict[T, int]
    def intern(self, val: T) -> int:
        idx = self._keys.setdefault(val, len(self._keys))
        if idx == len(self._values):
            self._values.append(val)
        return idx
    def unintern(self, idx: int) -> T:
        return self._values[idx]
    pass

def main():
    data = [1018, 1018, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1019, 1019, 1017]
    pool = Interner() # type: Interner[int]
    return [pool.intern(i) for i in data]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```